# Retrieve User's default industry role when adding to a project

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In BIM 360, when you add a new member, it is possible to assign the member a default role. This role is then assigned to the member when they are added to a project through the GUI. I am unable to find a way to duplicate this behavior through the API.

When adding a member to a project through the API via this endpoint: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/, it does not seem to automatically assign their default role when no role is specified.

Did I miss something, or is there an updated endpoint that will include the members default role? Barring that, is there an endpoint to view a members default role? I was unable to identify any in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding new members by calling [POST projects/:project_id/users/import](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/), you can get industry roles of that project via [GET projects/:project_id/industry_roles](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-industry_roles-GET/).

```bash
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v2/accounts/9dbb160e-b904-458b-bc5c-ed184687592d/projects/1e4bdc48-1bd7-4a4f-a91f-bd238cce5830/industry_roles' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer XZvCJNhdxESsBRIH28MfLf2hKL5O'
```

```json
[
  // ...

    {
        "id": "dc9e8af9-2978-4f6a-90b6-b294ae11c701",
        "project_id": "1e4bdc48-1bd7-4a4f-a91f-bd238cce5830",
        "name": "Civil Engineer",
        "services": {
            "document_management": {
                "access_level": "user"
            },
            "insight": {
                "access_level": "no_access"
            },
            "field_management": {
                "access_level": "no_access"
            },
            "project_administration": {
                "access_level": "no_access"
            },
            "assets": {
                "access_level": "no_access"
            }
        },
        "member_group_id": "86255267"
    },
]
```

Afterward, call [POST projects/:project_id/users/import](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/) with the industry role id you want for that user. For example,

```bash
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v2/accounts/9dbb160e-b904-458b-bc5c-ed184687592d/projects/1e4bdc48-1bd7-4a4f-a91f-bd238cce5830/users/import' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer hW0DvSvGgszPis1Yhot4c8kWW3NG' \
  -d '[
    {
      "email": "user@example.com",
      "services": {
        "document_management": {
          "access_level": "user"
        }
      },
      "industry_roles": [
        "dc9e8af9-2978-4f6a-90b6-b294ae11c701"
      ]
    }
   ]'
```

Comment: Thanks, @Eason. More specifically, I wanted to know how to get the **default role** for a user. I am already able to assign a project role to a user on a project, but I was hoping to get a users default role through the API, then assign it to them on a new project.